# Can I create graph edges between documents in cosmos db?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases

I have a cosmos db with a bunch of documents that were added through the documents api.

I used the graph client to create edges between those existing documents.

For example:

```
        await _client.CreateGremlinQuery<dynamic>(docCollection,
             $"g.V('{member.Id}')" +
             $".addE('post')" +
             $".to(g.V('{post.Id}'))")
             .ExecuteNextAsync();
```

This "works" and it creates the edge. The problem is when I want to fetch back the connected vertices for example, if i want all the post from a member, I would do:
`g.V('b45538e2-9ec3-4867-82d5-9b1cae1d921d').outE('post').inV` where the id is the member id.

This does bring back vertices connected from the edge, but it's not the document, its a "NativeVertex" with the same id as my document. I would expect the database to send me back the document itself since it is the vertex. The id are the same... When querying that id from the document api, I get  my proper document with all its properties, not a vertex.

Is there a way to fetch related documents from the Graph api?